# React Native Reanimated keeps giving error after upgrading expo to 47

Tags: reactjs, react-native, npm, expo, react-native-reanimated

This happened after I upgraded to expo 47 and reanimated to 2.13.0.

```
TypeError: _ReanimatedModule.default.configureProps is not a function. (In '_ReanimatedModule.default.configureProps(Object.keys(NATIVE_THREAD_PROPS_WHITELIST), Object.keys(UI_THREAD_PROPS_WHITELIST))', '_ReanimatedModule.default.configureProps' is undefined)
```

I had react-native-skeleton-content installed which has reanimated as a dependency for reanimated version 2.1.0.

I have tried using overrides in package.json and downgrading reanimated 2.3.1.

It seems like it's being caused by some version mismatch, but I haven't been able resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

I keep my version at the following:

```
"react-native-reanimated": "~2.12.0",
```

Make sure you add the proper config settings to your `babel.config.js` file:

```
module.exports = function (api) {
  api.cache(true);
    return {
      presets: ['babel-preset-expo'],
      plugins: ['react-native-reanimated/plugin'],
    };
};
```

Read more about it using `react-reanimated` with `expo` [here](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/reanimated/)